# problem with makro that worked for over a year now (runtime 1004)

Tags: runtime

I have a problem with one of my makro that worked so far for over a year now. It keeps on showing runtime error 1004 on paste.
The makro goes as:

```
Sheets("Allianz GI").Select
    Range("A1:J1000").Clear 
    Range("A1").Select
    
Dim IE As Object
 
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "https://pl.allianzgi.com/pl-pl/nasze-fundusze/fundusze/list?ShareClassCurrency=(PLN)" 
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:20"))

    IE.ExecWB 17, 0 '// zaznacz wszystko
    IE.ExecWB 12, 2 '// kopiuj
    
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True

    
    IE.Quit
    
    
End With
```

This makro has been working fine up until now and I have no idea what can I do to fix it.
Additionaly when the runtime error shows, when you select debug and then click run(F5) the makro resumes from the error line and goes on like nothing has happened and just pastes everything from the site.

What can I change to make this work again? Can I somehow force makro to ignore error and just do it without going into debug?

Comment: Did you try going to [the link you're accessing](https://pl.allianzgi.com/pl-pl/nasze-fundusze/fundusze/list?ShareClassCurrency=(PLN)) to assure nothing has changed there? Since your script has been untouched for all this time, the change is obviously external.

Comment: Yes, the link works fine. I have two makros like this for different sites. Today one worked and other didn't. Yesterday both failed to paste data. I think its the problem with copying from IE but I have no idea how to make it work all the time as the data is copying and you can force makro to work from debug.